# R Shiny - Numeric Input without Selectors

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to have a numeric input without the selectors? Every time the slider is pressed, all calculation in my app occur, so it could get choked up by a user easily. Possibly use a text input and cast it as numeric maybe?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You could use a textInput and have a `reactive()` that converts it to numeric so, for example, if `numInput` is the name of your textInput:

In server.R:

```
numConv <- reactive({as.numeric(input$numInput)})
```

Then anywhere that was referring to `input$numInput` change to `numConv()`. You can add any code you want the reactive, so you could do additional checks to make sure that the user is entering a valid input before it triggers all the other calculations in your app.

Comment: Yeah, that along the lines of what I was thinking too, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

In your ui.R file, use inputs like the following:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    sidebarPanel(
        textInput("text", "Enter Text:", "Default Text"),
        numericInput("num1", "Please Enter a Number:", 42)
      )
))
```

Hope that helps.