# Shiny numeric input with multiple option and NULL as initial

Tags: shiny

In Shiny `selectizeInput`, if nothing is selected, it returns `NULL`.

I wonder if there is a similar update version for numericInput which takes multiple values, e.g. `c(2,4)` or `5:9`, and returns `NULL` for missing input?

Comment: maybe this would help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960407/r-shiny-numeric-input-without-selectors

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you.